# Credentials manager with API

Tags: security, password-manager

During application development one often needs to store sensitive information locally. Even when using services such as Azure Key Vault, there's always one remaining weak link where a final secret needs to be stored unencrypted on disk.

Password managers, however, do it the right way: They stored everything encrypted and ask for a passphrase once per boot. A compromised machine (on the userspace-level anyway) cannot get at the credentials then (except by using keyloggers, but let's ignore that for now).

I'm looking for a "password manager" that has an API to allows local applications to retrieve them. It should only ask for a master credential once per boot.

Answer (score 1):

Hashicorp [Vault](https://www.vaultproject.io/) is one option. When set up correctly, you

- login/unseal the vault with your credentials once (I haven't looked to deep but it looks like it uses generated tokens as credentials)
- afterwards, secrets can be written/read via CLI or REST API